# Script for checking siebel application documents is viewable or not

Tags: automation, crm, siebel

As a part of routine healthcheck in Siebel application we open few documents from different navigation in Siebel application and check whether it is viewable in browser or not.
If i want to automate then can we prepare some script in which it returns the response code of the documents.

For ex :- 404 error code means not available. In the same way html response code between 200 to 400 means everything is alright.

OR

Any other ways in which i can know whether documents are viewable in browser or not.

Comment: Can you please add some additional information about the version of Siebel, Where the documents are stored (In Siebel FS or outside), what currently is used to view the documents.

Comment: Current version of siebel :- 8.1.1.5 and it will be upgraded to 8.1.11 in few days. 
Documents are stored in external system(Content Manager) and we view them via VBC.

Comment: Do you run Open UI or the old HI interface?

Comment: Currently its not open UI. We are using HI framework. We are going to migrate it to open UI soon.

Comment: Are the links to the document directly to the Content Management system or is the document first fetched to Siebel and then made available to the end user?

Comment: The documents are directly coming from content management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the browser directly accesses the documents from the browser, it would be best to record the manual executed event and then replayed. Tools like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/http-recording/http-recording.html). As it is probably a few requests at most one can look at recreating them using wget, or curl.

It is also possible to make this part of a larger test approach and include them in a open source test approach like [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/). It has a [HTTP Requests library](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/#readme) that allows you to perform tests using http requests. This in addition to the Web service, web browser, database and many other types of libraries that allow an integrated test approach.